# Excel bug: spreadsheet with a chart won't save anymore

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have Office 365 Home.

I have an Excel file consisting of a table of numeric data and a chart representation of this data. The file was created and last saved with Excel 2016.
Then when I got a notification about an Office update the file wouldn't save anymore, giving me the following error message:

> "Errors were detected while saving [filename]. Microsoft Excel may be able to save the file by repairing or removing some features. To make the repairs in a new file, click Continue. To cancel saving the file, click Cancel."

Excel wasn't able to repair the file. I assumed a bug had snuck in with the updated version, but apparently the update hadn't even installed yet. I had version 16.0.8229.2103, and updated to the most recent version, 16.0.8326.2059.

*Roan T* of Microsoft [suggested](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10/bug-report-excel-no-longer-can-handle-charts/a58c97b1-1c37-4222-ad81-bb8d11d41c2f) that I run the [Microsoft Office Configuration Analyzer Tool 2.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36852), which I did, but it didn't report any issues.

**How to reproduce**

I have Office installed on 2 computers, and the bug appears on both installations and is easy to reproduce.

Create a small table of numeric data, select it and insert a chart. (I used a scatter chart, but the problem pops up with other chart types too.)
Then format at least one cell in the table as numeric with *at least 3 decimal places*. Try to save the spreadsheet.

That when I get the error message. Can anyone please try this on his/her computer to see whether the bug is consistent?
Try to save in the default "Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)"; saving as .xls doesn't cause the issue.

***Question***
The bug may not show on every installation; though I know I'm not the only one. Is there a fix for this?

---

**update**
I tried both running Excel in safe mode and repair. No avail.

**update 2017-08-03**
At least [1 other person](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10/bug-report-excel-no-longer-can-handle-charts/a58c97b1-1c37-4222-ad81-bb8d11d41c2f) could reproduce it on version 8326.2062, but only on Windows 10. On Windows 7 there was no error.

Comment: Can you provide the actual data? I got 1,2,3,4,5 all in A1 to A5, and then some random numbers (between 0-99) in B1 to B5, and created a scatter plot as you said, Formatted B1 to "Numeric" with 3 decimal values, and it saves without issue. I am on Excel 16.0.8229.2086 (32-bit) - not sure if that make a difference?

Comment: @Darius - I used 1, 2 and 3 in column A, and 10, 4 and 5 in column B, but I get the error with any set of values. I formatted the 10 as 10.000, but also here it doesn't really matter which number you pick. I guess it has to do with your version being slightly older, or even the 32-bit (I thought I have 64-bit; where can I see that?). Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: If you click on File - Account - "About Excel" - it will open the About Microsoft Excel, and the top line will say what version (and 32/64 bit). I'll see if I can update it to your particular version and get the same bug. EDITED to add: I tried with your data, and same steps, add data, make scatterplot, format 10 to 3 decimal places, and save - still no error.

Comment: @stevenvh, it's a meta tag.  A "bug" could refer to most of the questions on the site without really differentiating anything (and people would use it for useless decoration).  We don't have any experts in bugs.  :-)

Comment: Are you saving this file locally or onto a network? Also, what are your locale settings? Under region in control panel. I wonder if something there has made this occur

Comment: @Dave - I'm saving it locally. It definitely has to do with the combination formatting-chart. I can perfectly save the file until 1) I format a number with at least 3 decimal positions, and 2) this number is on a chart. It doesn't look like locale has to do with it either, since 2 decimal digits works. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Does the order matter? I mean, if you format to 3 decimal places, and then add the chart, does the same issue occur?

Comment: @Dave - Yes, the same issue when I format first.

Comment: I have a somewhat older version `16.0.8229.2086` and cannot reproduce your problem.  What type of file did you save this as?  I will try to update to latest version.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Thanks, Ron. Darius has the same version, and didn't encounter the issue either. Neither did I until yesterday. My guess is that an automatic patch was done on my older version (probably 8229.2086), which left me with a buggy 8229.2103. A subsequent update to 8326.2059 has the bug also. About file format: good point, because I'm saving as the default "Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)" format, and when I save as a legacy .xls everything is fine, except that I get a warning about some features not being saved in the old format. I'll add this to my question.

Comment: I am downloading office updates as we speak.  After it updates, I will test again.

Comment: After update I now have version16.0.8326.2062 (32-bit) and I cannot reproduce the error.  File saves normally as .xlsx file.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I had build ...2059, so I also updated to ...2062. Unfortunately the bug is still there. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Since a few people cannot reproduce it, there may be something about your environment that is causing the issue.  Have you tried to repair your Office365 installation?  Oh, and does it occur if you open Excel in Safe Mode?

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem on windows 10 office Build 8326.2062 but not on windows 7 with office Build Build 8326.2062.

Comment: Different machine windows 10 office Build 8326.2062 did not show the problem with

Comment: Odd. Do both machines have the latest Windows update?

Comment: Rather than "Can anyone reproduce this bug?" which is going to get you a lot of garbage "yes" "no" "no repro" or similar  it would be better if you asked for an actual solution to your problem. Presumably this is what you actually want but as it stands all you are getting is answers saying "me too!"

Comment: @Mokubai - You've got a point, but when you ask "Do you have the time?" you expect the other person to tell you the time, and not "yes", don't you? Anyway, IMO knowing if there are others is the first step to an answer.

Comment: Knowing if other people have the same problem should be found out by upvotes on the question. Your question has been protected due to too many "me too!" answers which will prevent more of them. Conversely to your point you don't go into a restaurant and ask "Do you do steak?" and just expect "a steak" because you've no idea what kind you'll get, you ask for "rib-eye, medium rare" because that is what you want. Assuming people know what you want may work for the simple things, but sometimes you should be specific. If all you want to know is that people have the same problem then so be it.

Comment: @Mokubai - Upvotes != Me too. Upvotes mean that the "question shows research effort; it is useful and clear".

Comment: Final comment then I'm out. My problem is with your question title. It is vague, unspecific and only inviting the kind of answers that will get your question protected. If you actually seek solutions then it could potentially be unprotected so that anyone who stumbles across the site can answer it, at the moment only users with 10 reputation will be able to answer it meaning that you are potentially loosing out on answers. While upvotes may not equal "me too" their meaning depends on whoever is reading the question, in a lot of cases it indicates interest, well written question *and* "me too."